# how to have a running program add tab panes javafx

Tags: javafx, tabs

Hello this is my question, In order to let a user add tabs with a new button would i need to create a whole new border panes and tab panes for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need if you have already created tabPane previously.

```
Button btn = new Button("add new tab");

btn.setOnAction( (e) -> {
    tabPane.getTabs.add(new Tab("new tab"), new VBox(new Label(Content)) );
});
```